# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.Matchers after adding dependency too pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap

When I launch soap service application I get this error from my console

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.Matchers
```

After research, I have added these three dependencies to the pom.xml and still the error still exists on launching the application

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
```

Grateful for any assistance received.

Comment: use hamcrest-all instead of hamcrest-library and hamcrest-core.

Comment: just did and thesame result after relaunching

Comment: In what part of your project do you use the ``Matcher`` class? Since the pom provides the lib only in the test scope, you can only use it in unit tests (java files in /src/test/java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>        
</dependency>
```

Comment: If this worked, you're using the ``Matcher`` class in the wrong scope. Unit tests are supposed to run during the ``test`` phase in maven.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicate the lib of hamcrest aren't present at classpath of your app.

If you are using the org.hamcrest.Matchers class at Runtime, is necessary to change your scope to compile or provided if your midleware provided the hamcrest lib.

The test scope use the lib only in the test lifecycle.

You can read more at [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)